# Write a text inside a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm working on this plot:

[image]

I need to write something inside the first plot, between the red and the black lines, I tried with `ax1.text()` but it shows the text between the two plots and not inside the first one. How can I do that?

The plot was set out as such:

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize = (12,7), tight_layout = True)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Without more code details, it's quite hard to guess what is wrong.

The [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html) works well to show *text box* on subplots. I encourage you to have a look at the documentation (arguments...) and try by yourself.

The text location is based on the 2 followings arguments:

- `transform=ax.transAxes`: indicates that the coordinates are given relative to the axes bounding box, with `(0, 0)` being the lower left of the axes and `(1, 1)` the upper right.
- `text(x, y,...)`: where `x`, `y` are the position to place the text. The coordinate system can be changed using the below parameter `transform`.

Here is an example:

```
# import modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create random data
x = np.arange(0,20)
y1 = np.random.randint(0,10, 20)
y2 = np.random.randint(0,10, 20) + 15

# Create figure
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize = (12,7), tight_layout = True)

# Add subplots
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.plot(x, y2)
ax2.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)

# Show texts
ax1.text(0.1, 0.5, 'Begin text', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax1.transAxes)
ax2.text(0.9, 0.5, 'End text', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform=ax2.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

*output*

[image]

Comment: Thank you I needed that "transform" arg!

Comment: What does the 'transform' argument do?

Comment: @VjayalakshmiK Have a look at the updated answer